# how my app can login in anyones phone?

Tags: android, facebook

I find that I can add user into testers so that they can login in my app, but how to let my app can logined in their phone and I need not add them into testers by myselfs just like  official app?

Comment: First of all you need to set your app public on top of Status&Review tab in app dashboard. And then you have to submit all permissions you want to ask users for (apart from the three basic ones) for review. That process is very well documented, so go look at the login documentation.

Answer (score 1):

thank you I think I find the answer.It looks like because I have not complete the review. and thank you for your reply.